# ROC-AUC plot is in elbow shape

Tags: r, rstudio, roc

I want to create a ROC curve for my logistic regression model but my current code is not giving me the traditional or desired result. Below is the code: -

```
over3 <- SMOTE(pol ~., data = train, perc.under = 150)
over3

set.seed(645)
logit_model4 <- glm(pol ~., data = over3, family = "binomial")
logit_model4
summary(logit_model4)

fitted.results4 <- predict(logit_model4, test, type = "response")
fitted.results4

fitted.results4 <- ifelse(fitted.results4 > 0.5, 1, 0)
fitted.results4

table(test$pol, fitted.results4)

library(pROC)

pim <- roc(response = test$pol, predictor = fitted.results3, partial.auc = c(100,90),
    partial.auc.correct = T, percent = T)
plot(pim)
```

with the resulting figure as follows: -
[image: my plot]

However, I want the plot's output to be in the traditional way i.e.:-
[image: desired plot]

Hope someone can help me out

Comment: It looks like you've got only one predictor variable, and it is dichotomous. While the result is not wrong, you probably want to try adding more predictors to your model and see if the AUC increases. In any case, you should provide more information in your question, at least your model call.

Comment: 'over3 <- SMOTE(pol ~., data = train, perc.under = 150)
   over3

   set.seed(645)
   logit_model4 <- glm(pol ~., data = over3, family = "binomial")
   logit_model4
   summary(logit_model4)

   fitted.results4 <- predict(logit_model4, test, type = "response")
   fitted.results4

   fitted.results4 <- ifelse(fitted.results4 > 0.5, 1, 0)
   fitted.results4'

The above is my training and prediction code.

Comment: Not here! Reading R code is too difficult. Consider the folks here and edit your question with that information.

Comment: You build your curve with `fitted.results3`, I assume you meant `fitted.results4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't dichotomize your results!**

```
fitted.results4 <- ifelse(fitted.results4 > 0.5, 1, 0)
```

The ROC curve is built by assessing every possible threshold. By dichotomizing your result, you are preventing that from happening.

Instead you should use the quantitative predicted probabilities directly:

```
fitted.results4 <- predict(logit_model4, test, type = "response")
library(pROC)
pim <- roc(response = test$pol, predictor = fitted.results4, partial.auc = c(100,90), partial.auc.correct = T, percent = T)
plot(pim)
```